# How to display the latest entry in a log with logstash?

Tags: logging, logstash, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I am parsing an application log. A log entry has multiple lines so I use the multiline facility and define one log entry from the moment the timestamp pattern is matched until another timestamp is matched. The problem with this is that the latest entry will never be sent ( It will be when a new entry is added, but then it will not be the latest). Bellow is the configuration I have:

```
codec => multiline {

 pattern => '^20%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})'
            negate => true
            what => 'previous'
 }
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this ?

Comment: The multiline filter has a max_age parameter that seems applicable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how is it applicable? And i am using the multline codec which, according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html), does not have the max_age parameter

Comment: The way I read your original post is that the last message is waiting to be sent.  A timeout would help with that, right?  The filter has a timeout (where the codec does not).  Thus, my note that you might try the filter.  Or not; your choice.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying I will try it and come back with the result

Comment: Thank you I had time to test it and it worked...it does come with the limitation that you can use only one worker thread tough